# What does "Class _NSZombie_OS_voucher is implemented in both ?? and ??" mean?

Tags: xcode, nszombie

I got the following message in Xcode when I had both Address Sanitizer and Zombie Objects enabled in my scheme's diagnostics options, and ran the project:

```
objc[656]: Class _NSZombie_OS_voucher is implemented in both ?? and ??.
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I disabled Zombie Objects and the above message went away, but it won't come back if I turn Zombie Objects back on.

What does the message mean?

Comment: the same started to happen to me after updating to El Capitan from Yosemite with Xcode 6.4. it doesn't seem to affect anything though.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Same here. It comes and goes but I don't see any effects from it. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: As per this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514269/enabling-zombie-objects-on-xcode-7-gm-causes-class-nszombie-bsxpcmessage-is-imp

Performing a "Reset Content and Settings..." on the iOS Simulator cleared this up for me.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from vaticRite was helpful.

Stop your app and clean the project.

From the simulator click 'simulator' and then 'reset content and settings'