# Enabling zombie Objects on Xcode 7 GM causes Class _NSZombie_BSXPCMessage is implemented in both ?? and?

Tags: ios, xcode

Just downloaded XCode 7 GM and give a try on iOS 9 simulator of my app. However, I got a strange message on the console:

`objc[2213]: Class _NSZombie_BSXPCMessage is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

I then googled and no luck. If I disable the enable zombie objects in scheme settings, the message is gone. What's wrong?

Update: I tested it again on Xcode 6.4, no this problem.

Comment: I got the same. Would love to know why & how to fix.

Comment: I have 7.1 Xcode but still the same

Answer (score 8):

First of all delete your installed application from ios simulator or device,after that clean your projects.
When you will run your application, it should run your Projects properly without any errors.

I have also faced same problem.I have used above, it was worked for me.

If above is not working, so please clean your build cmd+alt+shift+k and also reboot your ios simulator from hardware menu.
it should run your Projects properly without any errors.

Comment: For me it looks like it helps. The message is gone.

Comment: Also let your machine cool down, flash your P-Ram and do not look at Stackoverflow for another 24 hours. If that doesn't work, wait for another drop of Xcode.